# What is a word or an expression to describe "forgetting things after being back from holiday"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've been away for a week or two from work and upon returning back to work, I've been a bit out-of-tune and have forgotten some normal procedures at work. Is there a word or an expression to correctly describe this situation? I want to say something like below - perhaps there is a better way to put this.

> Oh yes. I've completely forgotten! Looks like I'm still having a holiday effect.

Comment: The usual idiom nowadays is to say you are "still trying to get back up to speed following your holiday".

Comment: "I'm still *retraining* after my vacation.

Answer (score 1):

It is called ***Post-Vacation Syndrome (PVS)***

> It  appears in victims after returning to school/work after a vacation of a week or more. PVS is most common after summer, winter, and spring breaks in grade school and college students. There is no cure for PVS. The victim simply has to wait for it to clear on its own. 
>   ***-Symptoms include morning lag, skipping class, and late homework. Some cases of forgotten locker combinations have also been reported.***

Comment: Where's the quote from? Please add your source.